# Is there anyway in Typescript to get the type of an undefined class property?

Tags: typescript

Consider you have defined a class with a property like below but not yet set that property. Is there anyway to detect what type that property should be?

```
class User {

  username: string;
}

let user = new User();
console.log(typeof user.username) // string ???
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Types are erased. You can see this yourself by looking at the emitted JavaScript file; it is identical whether you wrote `username: string` or `username: number`.

Comment: I guess you would know

Comment: I wonder if decorators could address something like this in the future